# Help prove: $X,Y$ are conditionally independent given $Z$ iff $\Bbb P(X,|Z,Y)=f(X,Z)$ for some function $f$

Tags: probability

Given three random variables $X,Y,Z$, show that (Here $P$ represents probability mass or density)

> $X,Y$ are conditionally independent given $Z$ iff $ P(X,|Z,Y)=f(X,Z)$ for some function $f$.

One direction is quite easy. If $X \perp Y|Z$ (use $\perp$ to denote independence), then $ P(X|Z,Y)=P(X|Z)$, where $P(X|Z)$ is a function only dependent on $X,Z$.

I get stuck with the other direction. Although this is intuitively true, I could not figure out how to show it rigorously. Thank you!

---

P.S.

[image]

---

Proof of one direction:
Here $P$ represents discrete probability or probability density, not the probability measure. Notation like $P(X|Z)$ is short for $P(X=x|Z=z)$. Also assume $P(Z)>0$

If $X,Y$ are independent given $Z$, then

$P(X,Y|Z) = \frac{{P(X,Y,Z)}}{{P(Z)}} = P(X|Z)P(Y|Z) = \frac{{P(X,Z)P(Y,Z)}}{{P(Z)P(Z)}} \Rightarrow P(X,Y,Z) = \frac{{P(X,Z)P(Y,Z)}}{{P(Z)}} \Rightarrow \frac{{P(X,Y,Z)}}{{P(Y,Z)}} = \frac{{P(X,Z)}}{{P(Z)}} = P(X|Z)$

Then $P(X|Z,Y) = \frac{{P(X,Y,Z)}}{{P(Z,Y)}} = P(X|Z)$, which is a function only dependent on $X,Z$

Comment: "One direction is quite easy. If $X \perp Y|Z$ (...) then $\Bbb P(X|Z,Y)=\Bbb P(X|Z)$" How do you show this? The conditional independence $X \perp Y|Z$ means that $P(X,Y\mid Z)=P(X\mid Z)P(Y\mid Z)$, which is not the property you are using.

Comment: @Did Hi thanks for reply. I added the proof.

Comment: Right, but then, if you are fluent with this kind of manipulations of Bayes rule, I fail to see your problem in solving the exercise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition of conditional independence asserts that:
$$X\perp Y \mid Z ~\iff~ \mathsf P(X\mid Y,Z) = \mathsf P(X\mid Z)$$

The theorem states:

$$\exists f ~\big[ \mathsf P(X\mid Y, Z) = f(X, Z)\big] ~\implies~ X\perp Y \mid Z $$

In essence you are ask to show that *if* the conditional probability of $X$ given both $Y$ and $Z$ does equal some function in terms of only $X$ and $Z$, that that function must be the conditional probability of $X$ given $Z$.

That is: prove: $\forall f ~\Big[~\mathsf P(X\mid Y, Z)=f(X,Z) ~\to~ \mathsf P(X\mid Z) = f(X,Z)~\Big]$

---

**Hint:** Start with the Law of Total Probability.